# How often I have to do action X, with a $10\%$ chance of a reward, to have a $99\%$ chance of getting said reward?

Tags: probability

In a game I play, there is a $10\%$ chance of getting the item I want when I complete a certain action. I'd like to know how often I need to do said action to be $99\%$ sure I will have this item.

Comment: How often or how many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of having no items after $n$ attempts is $0.9^n$.

The probability of having at least one item after $n$ attempts is $1-0.9^n$.

So you need to solve the inequality $1-0.9^n\geq0.99$:

$1-0.9^n\geq0.99 \implies 0.9^n\leq0.01\implies n\geq\log_{0.9}0.01 \implies n\geq43.7 \implies n=44$.